# Disable statement not executing at a particular value

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

[image]I have written a code for counter and i'm implementing the disable statement. The counter has to count for particular value and exit the block once it reaches the value.

Here is the code:

```
module counter(
    );
    parameter number_of_count = 37;
    
    reg clk;
    integer count;
    
    initial
        begin
            count = 5;
            clk = 1'b0;
            forever #10 clk = ~clk;
        end
    
    always @(posedge clk)
        begin: this_block
            count = count + 1;
            $display ($time, " The present count is %d", count);
                repeat (number_of_count == count)
                    begin
                        count = 5;
                        disable this_block;
                    end
        end 
endmodule
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I want the counter to stop counting at 37 and exit the block. But as you can see in the waveform it continues to count again from 5. If i remove the count = 5 inside repeat it continues to count.

Comment: your code with the disable statement and the repeat block does not makes much sense. The disable statement does not do anything in your code. The repeat will probably work but it is just a programming hack which has no justification. Use an 'if' statement instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way is to use a `while` loop:

```
module counter;
    parameter number_of_count = 37;
    
    reg clk;
    integer count;
    
    initial
        begin
            count = 5;
            clk = 1'b0;
            forever #10 clk = ~clk;
        end
    
    initial begin
        while (count < number_of_count) begin
            @(posedge clk);
            count = count + 1;
            $display ($time, " The present count is %d", count);
        end
    end
endmodule
```

In your code, the block named `this_block` is executed at every posedge of `clk`.  Your `disable` simply disables the current instance of the block execution.  Since it is the last statement in the block, you really don't see any effect of the `disable`.  The block is re-enabled on every posedge of `clk`.  This is an unusual usage of `disable`.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 9.6.2 *Disable statement*.

Note: `disable` is rarely used, and I recommend against trying to use it here.